# MySQL wrong output with IN clause and parameter

Tags: mysql, delphi, parameters, delphi-xe

I'm having a hard time with a query in MySQL.

I'm working with Delphi XE and I'm sending a query with some parameter to MySQL. Here's an example for the query:

```
SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.id IN (:idUsers);
```

The ':idUsers' is the variable that will receive the parameter I send with Delphi, which is a string containing that is formatted like this, ex.: 1,2,3

The problem is that with this string, I receive only the first user (id = 1). From what I can see, its just like MySQL is adding some quote ('') at the beginning and at the end of the string I send, like if it was '1,2,3' instead of 1,2,3. I've tried this select :

```
SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.id IN ('1,2,3');
```

and it does indeed return only the first user..

I had a function in MSSQL that was splitting the string I sended and returning a temporary table, but we recently switched to MySQL, and from what I read, MySQL doesn't allow returning a table.

Anyone has a clue on how to solve this problem? I've been scrapping the Web for an answer and haven't found one for this specific problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can u paste your code here? I have been using a query of similar kind and haven't discovered this error any time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Parameters don't work like that; they have no idea that what you're trying to provide is a comma-separated list of values. If you set `ParamByName('WhatEver').AsString` or `Value`, it thinks you mean a quoted string that contains everything that belongs in that parameter. So it's doing exactly what it appears to - it's passing `IN ('1, 2, 3')`, instead of the intended `IN (1, 2, 3)`.

You'll need to either go back to parsing it out yourself and using a temp table, or build the `WHERE` clause dynamically and concatenating it before executing the query. (Actually, you could build the query dynamically, creating a new parameter for each of the items in the `IN` clause, and then loop through and assign values to each of those dynamically created parameters, but that gets very ugly very quickly.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Concatenating the query inside Delphi and then executing the query works. Building the query dynamically wouldn't have worked since I'm fetching the query from a table that contain all queries needed in the application. What I did is replace the parameter ":idUsers" by "$idUsers" and inside Delphi I'm doing a AnsiStrReplace of "$idUsers" with a string I built beforehand.

Comment: :) I'm glad you got it working. Sounds like a fine solution (as long as you don't have to worry about SQL injection).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable number of parameters in the IN clause, you could build a temporary table in MYSQL (which only contains a column called ID), load the parameter values into the temporary table and then do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.id IN (SELECT ID FROM TEMPTABLE);
```

As long the TEMPTABLE only contains the values you want to query, the table space scan is acceptable.

You can then have a variable number of values. You could also make the table permanent, and store the parameters. Add a column for the User, and each user can store their individual parameters.

Comment: This has already been mentioned, both in the original question and in my answer. :)